# Checking Null Cells within MySql Table

Tags: mysql, asp.net

i just wander if there is  away to check `MySql` `asp` Table if its Cells has Values or Not .

> **i'v used** this to return if Database has Row/Record there

```
 string ConnectionString = @"Server=MYSQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Database=db_9d6c52_ahmed;Uid=9d6c52_ahmed;Pwd=******;";
            MySqlConnection GetConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            GetConnection.Open();
            string VoiceorScreenSearch = "Select User_Voice ,User_Screen From User where User_Stat=@UserStat";
            MySqlCommand Comand = new MySqlCommand(VoiceorScreenSearch, GetConnection);
            Comand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"UserStat", key);
            MySqlDataReader ReadData = Comand.ExecuteReader();
            if (ReadData.HasRows)
            {

                    hasrowsornot = true;


            }
```

but i need it to return if `Cell[1]` is `null` or Has data !, My Cells Datatype is `BLOB`

and tips of doing this ? , will be helpful 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if (!ReadData.IsDbNull(yourfield)) {
    var value = ReadData.GetString(yourfield);
    // some code
}
```

Comment: should i write my field name or my field number ?